# How to connect Crystal Report to local database?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, ssms

I am trying to connect local database to my crystal report for development and testing purpose, but an error shows up saying 'database logon failed'.

When i changed the database logon to live server, it works out fine.

Below are the codes i tried:

```
ReportDocument myDataReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
            this.CrystalReportViewer1.ID = (Request.QueryString["ncrno"]).ToString();
            myDataReport.Load(Server.MapPath("CNCR.rpt"));
            myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "1234", @".\SQLEXPRESS", "INTRANET");            
            myDataReport.SetParameterValue("NCR No.", (Request.QueryString["ncrno"]).ToString());
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myDataReport;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

I also tried change the database logon to:

```
myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "1234", @"PC00001-MYPC-\SQLEXPRESS", "INTRANET");
```

But still failed.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only single instance installed, use

myDataReport.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "1234", ".", "INTRANET");

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately not working. Same error occur.

Comment: it seems your credentials are not valid.

Comment: But i can login with the same credentials on my ssms

Comment: oh, then I would prefer to use windows authentication for local, give it a try.